# How to display DropDownList dataloading faster in client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using C# ASP.NET 3.5 in my application. In my application, I do have a page where a DropDownList is populated based on another DropDownList select value.

Each of my DropDownList has an selectedIndexChange method on its selection. Due to this data retrieval is slower.

Is there any client side AJAX tools to handle this to make it faster? Please advise.

I have attached an image of my page.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.There is an ajax control named CascadingDropDown

```
  <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlportfolio" TargetControlID="ddlportfolio" 
                                        PromptValue="" ServicePath="ServiceVB.asmx" ServiceMethod="Getportfolio" runat="server" 
                                        Category="portfolio" LoadingText = "Loading..." />
```

Comment: Is there any other technique apart from ajax or javascripts, in order to ascertain the above?

Comment: this control is used for making change on others. i think this is the best one

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('#<%=ddlstate.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#<%=ddlcity.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#<%=ddlstate.ClientID %>').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select State</option>');
$('#<%=ddlcity.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Region</option>');
$('#<%=ddlcountries.ClientID %>').change(function() {
var country = $('#<%=ddlcountries.ClientID%>').val()
$('#<%=ddlstate.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
$('#<%=ddlcity.ClientID %>').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Region</option>');
$('#<%=ddlcity.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "jQueryCascadingDropdownExample.aspx/BindStates",
data: "{'country':'" + country + "'}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
var j = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
var options;
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>'
}
$('#<%=ddlstate.ClientID %>').html(options)
},
error: function(data) {
alert('Something Went Wrong')
}
});
});
```

Please refer the below link.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/10/jquery-cascading-dropdown-list-in-aspnet.html

Comment: Is there any other technique apart from ajax or javascripts, in order to ascertain the above?